# How to run pre-compiled C code within TCL?

Tags: c, tcl

I would like to re-write some critical functions in C to gain speed, I'm working on large amounts of input data so the benefit could be significant.

In my environment, I don't have a C compiler so I can't go for a "compile during run-time" approach. The C files should be compiled and functions called and executed from compiled files. How can I do this?

Comment: Compile the files at compile time? What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should write some bridging functions and package it into a loadable extension DLL (or whatever the right file extension is for your platform).

A reasonable place to start is the [sample extension](https://core.tcl.tk/sampleextension/dir?ci=trunk). The main code for that is in `generic/sample.c` (it's just a SHA-1 implementation, ordinary C code written in rather an old style). The code to bridge it into Tcl is in `generic/tclsample.c`, and consists of two functions.

- `Sha1_Cmd` is the code to implement a Tcl command in C. The name is formally arbitrary, but the type signature is not. The interesting Tcl API functions inside this are `Tcl_GetIndexFromObj`, `Tcl_GetString` (there's a `Tcl_GetStringFromObj` too with slightly different arguments), `Tcl_GetIntFromObj`, `Tcl_AppendResult`, `Tcl_SetObjResult`, and `Tcl_NewIntObj`. Unusually, the function *doesn't* call `Tcl_WrongNumArgs` for its processing of the case where the user passes in the wrong number of arguments.

  The usual pattern for command implementations is to first parse the arguments, working out whether what the command has been asked to do is sensible and returning errors (i.e., Tcl exceptions) when things aren't sensible. Then the underlying code is called to actually do the real task. Finally, the results of the underlying code — including any reported failures — are converted back into a form that can pass through Tcl. This pattern is *extremely* common.
- `Sample_Init` is the code to install the command into Tcl when you [`load`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/load.htm) the DLL. Both name and signature matter; the name has to match the computed library name with the suffix `_Init` (in this case, we're expecting to be called `sample.dll` or `libsample.so` or something like that). Take note that it calls `Tcl_InitStubs`, `Tcl_PkgProvide` and `Tcl_CreateObjCommand`. `Tcl_SetVar` (or one of its related functions) would also be reasonable, but this package happens not to do so.

The compilation instructions tend to vary a bit between platforms, but if you've ever built one extension DLL on one system then the others aren't really all that different.

Turning the DLL into a full package then requires adding a little `pkgIndex.tcl` along side it, and installation of the package becomes dumping the two files into the right directory (probably with setting the permissions right if you're doing a system install, etc). You can get a lot more complicated than that, but it's not too hard. For something application-specific, you instead keep the DLL/package-index file in a directory you control and extend Tcl's `auto_path` global variable before doing `package require`.

Comment: There are tools such as SWIG to generate the binding code for you. I usually dislike such automatically-generated interfaces because they produce code that feels C rather than code that feels like Tcl (or whatever other target language you're using).

Comment: Also, you compile/link once and then deploy the DLL to the production machines. Standard practice!